# LDAP gidNumber like Auto Integer

Tags: python, django, active-directory, ldap, openldap

Still working with LDAP...
The problem i submit today is this: i'm creating a posixGroup on a server LDAP using a custom method developed in python using Django framework. I attach the method code below.
The main issue is that attribute **gidNumber is compulsory of posixGroup class**, but usually is not required when using graphical LDAP client like phpLDAPadmin since they fill automatically this field like an auto-integer.
Here the question: **gidNumber is an auto integer attribute for default, or just using client like the quoted above? Must i specify it during the posixGroup entry creation?**

```
def ldap_cn_entry(self):

        import ldap.modlist as modlist

        dn = u"cn=myGroupName,ou=plant,dc=ldap,dc=dem2m,dc=it"

        # A dict to help build the "body" of the object
        attrs = {}
        attrs['objectclass'] = ['posixGroup']
        attrs['cn'] = 'myGroupName'
        attrs['gidNumber'] = '508'

        # Convert our dict to nice syntax for the add-function using modlist-module
        ldif = modlist.addModlist(attrs)

        # Do the actual synchronous add-operation to the ldapserver
        self.connector.add_s(dn, ldif)
```

- connector is first instanced in the constructor of the class where this method is built. The constructor provides also to the LDAP initialization and binding. Than, the connection will be closed by the destructor.
- to use the method i begin instancing the class it belongs, so it also connects to LDAP server. Than i use the method and finally i destroy the object i instanced before to close the connection. **All works, indeed, if use this procedure to create a different entry, or if i specify the gidNumber manually**.

  The fact is i CAN'T specify the gidNumber any time i want to create a group to goal my purpose. I should leave it filling automatically (if that's possible) or think about another way to complete it.

I'm not posting more code about the class i made to not throng the page.
I'll provide more information if needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LDAP protocol has no method for auto-integer.

You need to specify the value when creating the entry.

You can do some tricks to help.
We often put the last used value on an OU (We add an AUX class with custom Attribute to the OU) in LDAP and then read, increment and then use the value when using the gidNumber.

[Found this described](http://www.rexconsulting.net/ldap-protocol-uidnumber.html).
-jim

Comment: Okay. And what about if i then delete an entry? I'm leaving an "empty place" since LDAP is not capable to manage gidNumber automatically. Probably i should work on it, building a custom function to call when i need to assign a gidNumber...

Just the last question: is there any limit concerning max value of gidNumber or something like that? i.e. using phpLDAPadmin, posixGroups take their gidNumber automatically starting from 500, but i wonder if there is a max value like 999.

Comment: I built something similar to what you suggested me. And it works. I'm still studying how to solve some defects but actually i thank you. I post my code as a new answer so anyone can see it. If you ave any other suggestion i'll be great to read them

Answer (score 1):

Following @jeemster suggestion, i found the way to manage gidNumber.

Fist of all: i created a new entry on my LDAP called "gidNumber" and i added the optional attribute *description* to contain the last gidNumber i used (class: organizationalUnit, ou: gidNumber, description: 500).

Then i created the following functions:

```
def ldap_gid_finder(self):

        # Locates the suport-entry with a simple query
        self.baseDN = "ou=impianti,dc=ldap,dc=dem2m,dc=it"
        self.searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
        self.retrieveAttributes = None
        self.searchFilter = "ou=*gidNumber*"

        # Results are putted in a dictionary
        self.ldap_result = self.connector.search(
            self.baseDN, self.searchScope, self.searchFilter, self.retrieveAttributes)
        result_set = []
        while 1:
            result_type, result_data = self.connector.result(self.ldap_result, 0)
            if (result_data == []):
                break
            else:
                if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
                    result_set.append(result_data)

        # The attribute containing gidNumber is passed to an instanced variable
        self.actual_gid_number = int(result_set[0][0][1]['description'][0])

    # Provides to gidNumber incrementation
    def ldap_gid_increment(self):

        dn = "ou=gidNumber,ou=impianti,dc=ldap,dc=dem2m,dc=it"

        old = {'description': str(self.actual_gid_number)}
        new = {'description': str(self.actual_gid_number + 1)}

        ldif = modlist.modifyModlist(old,new)

        self.connector.modify_s(dn, ldif)
```

As i sad above, these methods are defined in a class of which i overrided constructor and destructor, in order to bind/unbind automatically to LDAP server when i instance or delete the instance.

Then, i used a query on LDAP to find the object called *gidNumber* (the ou i created before), and i filled a dictionary with resulting information. In the dictionary i found the variable representing the gidNumber and i used integer casting to manipulate it for incrementing. And that's all.

This procedure i really efficent because i server reboots you don't lose gidNumber information! Thank you again, jeemster.